# What does 16th (the identity matrix) generator of $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ stand for?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

While exploring the group $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ I have analyzed all its 15 generators.
As an example, they are explicitly given in [Elementary constituents of the group SL(4, R),](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6374)
These generators can be obtained by combining the products of the Dirac matrices and generate the 15 subgroups of $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$.
However, it appears (p.5) that there is also the 16th generator which is the identity matrix
$$
G_{16}=I=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_0&0\\
0&\sigma_0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Basically, all 16 generators are the same as the basis of the Clifford algebra $Cl(3,1)$ - which also includes $I$.
On the other hand, $SL(4,\mathbb{R})\cong SO(3,3)$, and the latter is the 15-dimensional group.
Does it imply that the 16th generator being the scalar multiply when added turns $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ into $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$? Or is it just a dummy element?

What does this generator signify? As I understand, it can be included in the basis for Lie algebra as it is not traceless.

Answer (score 1):

If one considers $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ as an abstract Lie group, and $\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{R})$ as an abstract Lie algebra, then there is no $16$th generator: both are $15$-dimensional and a set of generators is just a choice of basis of the Lie algebra.

That said, it is common to instead view $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ as a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$, and correspondingly view $\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{R})$ as a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(4,\mathbb{R})$. This is being done implicitly when one write elements of either as $4\times 4$ matrices. Since $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ has one less dimension than $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$, a superfluous extra "degree of freedom" will appear in various places.

In this case, that extra degree of freedom is a subgroup in its own right: if we view $\mathbb{R}^*$ as the subgroup of scalar matrices $\{cI:c\neq 0\}\subset GL(4,\mathbb{R})$, we have the decomposition $GL(4,\mathbb{R})\cong SL(4,\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}^*$, and $G_{16}=I$ is one choice of generator of this $\mathbb{R}^*$ subgroup.